# Web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionCall Is not working

Tags: transactions, ether, metamask, javascript, wei

I'm creating a dapp that charges users a specific amount of eth depending on their input.

Whenever I attempt to create the transaction, I specify the amount of Eth in Wei. It throws an Error with no description as to why it couldn't fulfill the transaction

**Error: Error Minting New NFT
at MintNewNFT (Transactions.js:68)
at Object.onClick (index.js:62)**

*(Line 62 is the catch block)*

**AmountIn is 0.02166 ETH**

Here is my code :

```
 export const MintNewNFT = async (WalletABI,address, network, mediaID, amountIn) => {

  try {
    
    
    //adjust this to take an argument for media id
    
    const web3 = new Web3('https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/key');
    const weiValue = Web3.utils.toWei(amountIn.toString(), 'ether');
    console.log(weiValue , mediaID);
    
    const transactionParameters = {
      to: WalletABI._address, // Required except during contract publications.
      from: address, // must match user's active address.
      value: weiValue.toString(), 
      data: web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionCall(    
        {
          "inputs": [
          {
            "internalType": "bytes32",
            "name": "mediaID",
            "type": "bytes32"
          }
        ],
        "name": "mintNewNFT",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "payable",
        "type": "function",
        "payable": true
        
      },[mediaID]),
      chainId: `0x${network}`, // Used to prevent transaction reuse across blockchains. Auto-filled by MetaMask.
    };
    
  
    
    // txHash is a hex string
    // As with any RPC call, it may throw an error
    await window.ethereum.request({
      method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
      params: [transactionParameters],
    }).then((result) => {

      // The result varies by by RPC method.
      // For example, this method will return a transaction hash hexadecimal string on success.

      console.log(`Transaction Result ${result}`)


    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // If the request fails, the Promise will reject with an error.

      console.log(`Transaction ERROR :  ${error.message}`)
    });

    

} catch (error) {
    throw Error("Error Minting New NFT", error)
}
}
```

Any indication as to what I may be doing wrong would be very much appreciated

Comment: What are the values of `amountIn` and `weiValue `?

Comment: Amount in :  0.02166  || toWei : 21660000000000000

Comment: i changed data param to web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionCall since it expects a parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.... I fixed my issue. Turns out it was failing because i was using a bytes32 instead of a string for the argument. i cant really explain why this happened incase anyone else can